# How to get a list of tables is database backup in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a list of database backup files and I want to see what tables are in each without loading them. How can I do this quickly ? I am suspicious that whoever loaded these files into a database perhaps did not do it properly. No logs available of when the load took place and what it brought in or in there were errors. This is a sql server 2012 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that the RedGate tools can peek inside a backup file, but it's a commercial product, not sure if there are any other free tools that can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can interpret what is inside sql server backup files with out restoring onto a development server.

but as long as you restore onto a dev server you shouldn't have any major concerns.